# BasicAuth in 4.2.1

Tags: atk4

I have noted that BasicAuth does no longer works by simply uncomented //->check in Frontend.php
It seems like now it requires a Model...
what are the requirements for that model? how do I create it?
And how do I know use BasicAuth?

Thanks

Comment: The Auth Test sample in a fresh installation does not work by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
$auth->setModel('AnyModel','user_field','password_field');
$auth->check();
```

This should work. The allow('demo','demo') attempt to pass on a Array-based model with specified user and there seems to be some bug in 4.2.1.

Added: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/67

Comment: Method is not defined for this object .... In red: /var/www/421/page/authtest.php :7  sample_project_basicauth BasicAuth->check()